# How to find system bios address in linux

Tags: memory, bios, smbios, flashrom

I want to do some interaction with bios of a embedded linux on an AMD Ryzen embedded platform.

The main tool I think is `flashrom` which can read/write flash chips.

It should also be possible to write data to flash rom using something like `dd` if the address of the chip in memory is known?

Is this the correct way to look for system bios:

```
root@device:~/bios# grep ROM /proc/iomem
    000c0000-000cd3ff : Video ROM
  000f0000-000fffff : System ROM
```

If I look for the rom using `flashrom` tool I get the following:

```
root@device:~/bios# flashrom -p internal --flash-name
flashrom v1.2 on Linux 5.4.199 (x86_64)
flashrom is free software, get the source code at https://flashrom.org

Using clock_gettime for delay loops (clk_id: 1, resolution: 1ns).
Found chipset "AMD FP4".
Enabling flash write... OK.
Found Winbond flash chip "W25Q64.W" (8192 kB, SPI) mapped at physical address 0x00000000ff800000.
vendor="Winbond" name="W25Q64.W"
```

So the `iomem` says the chip is at `000f0000-000fffff` and `flashrom` is saying he chip is at `0x00000000ff800000`

Which one is correct, or better yet, why these are not identical?

Answer (score 1):

> Which one is correct, or better yet, why these are not identical?

They are different, because they are different things. Neither are "correct".

What `flashrom` outputs is an address of a physical flash IC.

What iomem reports where some part of memory is mapped to in memory space; this might be some memory that itself is somewhere on a flash IC (maybe even the one you queried via `flashrom -p internal`, but more likely something that got copied or mapped to some part of RAM during early hardware initialization.

You have to realize that "BIOS", "Video ROM", … are IBM PC concepts that essentially do not at all apply to how hardware works nowadays. They are hence, if present, [completely emulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI#CSM_booting).

So, when you say "interaction with bios of a embedded linux on an AMD Ryzen", you are actually saying "I want to talk to a 38 year old API that gets somehow emulated by the firmware running on the processor I'm using"; it's not so easy to pinpoint who emulates what in that case, and superficially simple things like "there's the video ROM, which is a chip contains a font, and programs for the video BIOS", that's plain really not how the graphics hardware works. Same for the BIOS – what initializes the board and CPU is not some IBM PC-BIOS-derived software, but the firmware of your board and your CPU, including UEFI programs and Linux. The BIOS interface is really just some additional API offered optionally by the firmware.